# How to delete all children from a TTreeViewItem?

Tags: delphi, treeview, firemonkey

Is there a way to delete all children from a TTreeViewItem? I tried `DeleteChildren` but that causes crashes.

What I thought what was a simple question turns out to generate many more questions. That's why I explain of what I am trying to do.

My application tries to generate a directory tree in Delphi XE5 FMX. I use TTreeView for that. It starts by generating a list of drives, all of them TTreeViewItem's owned by TTreeView. When the user clicks on an item the directories below are added to the directory and the TTreeViewItem clicked upon expands. When the user clicks again the TTreeViewItem callapses. This has one caveat: the next time the user clicks on the same TTreeViewItem, the list of directories are added to the existing ones, see image below. In order to prevent that I would like to first clear the current list.

[image: A list of duplicated directories]

When I tried to delete the children using TreeViewItem.DeleteChildren from a TTreeViewItem I get an exception at another spot, see the picture below.

[image: Error message]

As to some questions: yes, I am sure I only add TTreeViewItems and this is the only Control I assign the OnClick event (import_directory_click). I have added the complete code and commented out the non-essentials to be sure.

I hope somebody tells me this functionality already exists (couldn't find it) but even then I would still like to know how to manage a TTreeView.

```
  procedure TMain.import_initialize;
  var
     Item: TTreeViewItem;
     drive: Char;
     start: string;
  begin
     Directory_Tree.Clear;

  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  // When Windows, just present a list of all existing drives
     for drive := 'C' to 'Z' do
     begin

  // A drive exists when its root directory exists
        start := drive + ':\';
        if TDirectory.Exists (start) then import_add (start, Directory_Tree);
     end; // for
  {$ELSE}
  // All other systems are unix systems, start with root.

     drive := '/';
     start:= drive;
     Item := import_add (TPath.GetPathRoot (start), DirectoryTree);
     import_get_dirs (Item, start);
  {$ENDIF}
     start := TPath.GetSharedPicturesPath;
     import_add (start, Directory_Tree);
     if start <> TPath.GetPicturesPath
        then import_add (TPath.GetPicturesPath, Directory_Tree);
  //   import_test_selection ('');
  end; // import_initialize //

  procedure TMain.import_directory_click (Sender: TObject);
  var
     TreeItem: TTreeViewItem;
     obj: TFMXObject;
     first_file: string;
  begin
     GridPanelLayout.Enabled := False;
     if Sender <> nil then
     begin
        TreeItem := Sender as TTreeViewItem;
        if TreeItem.IsExpanded then
        begin
           TreeItem.CollapseAll;
        end else
        begin
           TreeItem.DeleteChildren; // <== this statement
           import_get_dirs (TreeItem, TreeItem.Text);
  {
           first_file := find_first (TreeItem.Text, Selected_Images);
           if first_file <> '' then
           begin
              Image.Bitmap.LoadFromFile (first_file);
              GridPanelLayout.Enabled := True;
           end; // if
  }
           TreeItem.Expand; // <== causes an exception over here
        end; // if
     end; // if
  end; // import_directory_click //

  procedure TMain.import_get_dirs (Start_Item: TTreeViewItem; start: string);
  var
     DirArray: TStringDynArray;
     DirArraySize: Int32;
     i: Int32;
  begin
     DirArray := TDirectory.GetDirectories (start);
     DirArraySize := Length (DirArray);
     for i := 0 to DirArraySize - 1
        do import_add (DirArray [i], Start_Item);
  end; // get_dirs //

  function TMain.import_add (dir: string; owner: TControl): TTreeViewItem;
  var
     TreeItem: TTreeViewItem;
  begin
     TreeItem := TTreeViewItem.Create (owner);
     TreeItem.text := dir;
     TreeItem.OnClick := import_directory_click;
  //   TreeItem.Parent := owner;
     owner.AddObject (TreeItem);
     Result := TreeItem;
  end; // import_add //
```

Comment: "causes crashes" Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Jerry, you are right. See the update of the question.

Comment: Not sure how you expect to `TreeItem.Expand` if you've deleted everything it contains. `DeleteChildren` deletes all of the children and sets `Children` to nil, according to the docs.

Comment: What are the addresses it gives you in the access violation? They're more important than you may think :-)

Comment: Well first, what is TMain.import_directory and are you sure the sender is actually a TTreeViewItem?

Comment: Your remarks made me rephrase the question as it was not clear enough. I hope to have answered your questions till now.

Comment: Why not just call `DeleteChilden` instead of `CollapseAll`? Usage of `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` should also be considered!

Comment: @splash - when the node is expanded, it should collaps (hence the CollapseAll), when it is collapsed, it should expand and read all its subdirectories (and deleting the current list). As I explained, I tried DeleteChildren and that causes the exception.

Comment: But shouldn't a `DeleteChildren` give the same effect as a collapse? If the children are deleted then they aren't expanded anymore, hence the node is collapsed. ;-) Well, the collapse/expand indicator icon would disappear too, but it is neither available in the tree's initial state.

Comment: @splash - DeleteChildren deletes the children from the Item, hence the node cannot be expanded anymore, unless one adds children again. If the children are *not* deleted and new children are added I simply duplicate the entries. The first image show when I expand and collapse the TreeItemView several times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that TreeItem.DeleteChildren deletes the item content site instead of the subitems.
I suggest to use this:

```
for i := TreeItem.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    TreeItem.RemoveObject(TreeItem.Items[i]);
```

Comment: That's it! I had done something almost similar: I operated upon the children, e.g. `TreeItem.Children.Count` and `TreeItem.Children.RemoveObject (i)`' That yields quite weird results. Thank you very much! Everything works as expected.